# Errors installing Rails on Mac with Yosemite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, byebug

I've tried to install bye bug but am getting the following error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./../../extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/byebug-3.5.1

I am running Yosemite.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What command do you run that produces this error? Is this installing Rails or bye bug? Is Ruby installed correctly? You need to give some helpful information.

Comment: I ran gem install bye bug,  and yes ruby is installed correctly - although having said that, how can i test?  apologies, absolute beginner.

Comment: This is the full return from gem install bye bug command... Fetching: slop-3.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed slop-3.6.0
Fetching: byebug-3.5.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/Users/smacc01/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Successfully installed byebug-3.5.1
Parsing documentation for slop-3.6.0
Installing ri documentation for slop-3.6.0

Comment: To get a good answer you need to ask a good question; in your original question the title seems to say you're installing Rails, not a gem. You also don't say if Rails, Ruby and other dependencies are installed or what you did that led to the error. This is why your question got down voted. I'd guess you need to run `gem install` as root.

Comment: Parsing documentation for byebug-3.5.1
Installing ri documentation for byebug-3.5.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - ./../../extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/byebug-3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

You can refer these two site for the installation of ruby on rails on mac, might help you

```
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite
http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html
```